# grouping of numbers in excel

Tags: excel, vba

If I have a long series of numbers, lets say `(22, 20, 18, 24, 27, 23, 19, 18, 21, 22, 24)`,
I want them to be categorized using `VBA` in the following format (combination from low to high):

1. 22 (since 20 is less than 22) first column will make a group with single value of "22"
2. 20 (since 18 is less than 20) second column will make a group with single value of "20"
3. 18 ( numbers in series after that: 24, 27) now 3rd Column will have values like: 18, 24, 27 (now 23 is less than 27, it will break the group)
4. 23 (next number 19 is less than 23, break the group to one value of 23)
5. 19 (next number is 18, less than 19) break group to display single value 19
6. 18 (next number is 21 greater than 18, after that 22 greater than 21, 24 greater than 22) group will be 18, 21, 22, 24
7. and so on with all possible combination if the last column value is less than the next number.

### final outcome will be:

```
22   
20  
18, 24, 27 (18 less than 24 less 27)  
27  
23  
19  
18, 21, 22, 24 (18 less than 21 less than 22 less than 24)  
21, 22, 24  (21 less than 22 less than 24)  
22,24 (22 less than 24)  
24
```

Answer (score 1):

In my example, your numbers are listed in the first row, i.e. in cells A1 to K1. The following code produces the output on row 3:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim tmpString As String
Dim group As Range
Range("A2").Value = "Groups:"
Set group = Range("A3")
For Each cell In Range("A1:" & Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Address)
    tmpString = tmpString & ", " & cell.Value
    If (cell.Value > cell.Offset(0, 1).Value Or IsNull(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value)) Then
        group.Value = Right(tmpString, Len(tmpString) - 2)
        Set group = group.Offset(0, 1)
        tmpString = ""
    End If
Next
```

The output puts "22" in A3, "20" in B3, "18, 24, 27" in C3 etc...

Comment: Thanks Carmelid, sorry but the code didn't work. It should group them from low to high but the code has failed to do so.

Comment: Thanks @Carmelid, I tried your code and it worked like a charm but my data is in range "B" (xlDown) how can make it work ? As you had used an example in cells A1 to K1 but it's not working with my sheet since the data I have in vertical B Range. Please help me with the modifications. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Gautam, In the For Each-part you loop through the cells you want to Group, and the groupt variable is where you put the results. So an edit, for data in column B (starting at B1), you'll have to edit the For-loop to:
    For Each cell in Range("B1:" & Range("B1").End(xlDown).Address

Then edit the Group variable, so if you'd like to have the output in column C, simply set the Group Before the loop to the first cell you want to write to:   Set Group=Range("C1")
Then move one step down in each loop:
Set Group = Group.Offset(1,0)  *Note that this is moving down instead of left.
Good luck